# Which graph has same Breadth-First traversal and Depth-First Traversal?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, traversal

I was just wondering if it is possible for two graphs to have the same breadth-first and depth-first traversal. The graph may be directed or undirected.

Comment: A graph having a linear structure(chain) has same BFS and DFS traversal and it will be tree with `n` nodes and `n-1` edges.

Comment: @SanketMakani Even in that case, the starting node is rather significant.

Comment: Yes, Traversal should be from any of the nodes present at the ends of a chain.

Comment: A one-vertex graph.  (This should really be interpreted as a hint to think about whether the question you asked is really the question you wanted an answer for.)

Comment: Also a complete graph -- since all traversals are equivalent, every DFS ordering is also a BFS ordering and vice-versa

Answer (score -1):

A connected, undirected graph where there are `N` nodes and `(N-1)` edges, and where there is only two nodes with the degree `1` (i.e. the other `(N-2)` nodes would have the degree `2`) could have the same visiting order for BFS and DFS **provided that you start from one of the nodes with degree `1`.** If you start from one of the nodes with rank `2`, the traversal order would differ.

Thinking of linearly traversing through a singly linked list may help you visualize it better.

Comment: First things first, notice the keyword **connected** in my definition. "a graph with 2 nodes of degree 1 and N-2 nodes of degree 2" may describe the setting you mentioned, but when the graph is defined as **connected** that is not the case. Secondly, yes, the graph I defined can also be described as a tree, but whether it is a tree or not is irrelevant, at least within the scope of the question. So, you kind of pointed out 2 distinctions without any difference, and former one wasn't even accurate.

Comment: It's unclear whether "connected, undirected" extends to the sentence part after the comma, but I was certainly mistaken to write "necessarily" there (don't know how I forgot about paths), sorry about that.  Regarding trees, I'm not sure what the problem is -- it's just a concise way of describing something you were needlessly spelling out.

Comment: The conjunctive word _and_ seems to make things sufficiently clear to me, but the OP (and anyone else) is obviously welcome to check out this productive correspondence you and I have been having for further clarification. Also, thank you for your help in a more concise answer.

Comment: By "A connected, undirected graph where there are N nodes and (N-1) edges, and one where there is only two nodes with the degree 1 (i.e. the other (N-2) nodes would have the degree 2)", do you actually mean just a single class of graphs (paths)? If so, delete "one", because currently the sentence describes two different classes of graphs that satisfy the OP's requirements (namely "A connected, undirected graph where there are N nodes and (N-1) edges" and "[a connected, undirected] one where there is only two nodes with the degree 1 (i.e. the other (N-2) nodes would have the degree 2)").

Comment: If they were two separate classes of graphs, I would use the word _or_ , as both classes would satisfy the requirements set by OP. Again, I believe the meaning is clear enough, but these comments will clarify any second user that may find it ambiguous.

Comment: "and" or "or" is not the problem.  "I have an apple that is red, and one that is big" always means I have 2 apples -- one is red, the other is big.  "I have an apple that is red, and [that is] big" means I have 1 apple, and it is simultaneously red and big.